# How to calculate timedifference in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

How can we calculate the difference between two datetimes in SSRS.
and display the result in a time format

Like for eg:

```
   Date1                            Date2                     Calculate   
2015-08-02 08:20:00             2015-08-02 10:20:00           02:00:00
```

We can easily calculate arithmetic operation, I want to know can we calculate time difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateDiff(Hour,Date1,Date2)

```
Datediff(Hour,'2015-08-02 08:20:00','2015-08-02 10:20:00')
```

will result in 2

time from parts can be used in SQL2012

```
 timefromparts( Datediff(Hour,'2015-08-02 08:20:00','2015-08-02 10:20:00'),0,0,0,0)
```

will convert that result to a time format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use DATEDIFF. Full details [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/datediff.php)